# Не могу корректно удалить нужный элемент массива

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно удалить элемент массива из локального хранилища, а затем снова перезаписать этот массив. Но я столкнулся со странной проблемой.

Вот мой код:

```
let removeItemFromFavorite = document.querySelectorAll('.remove_item');

removeItemFromFavorite.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function(){
      let remCollectionAlert = document.querySelector('.rem-collection-alert');
      let dataTitle =  this.getAttribute('data-title');
      let dataItem =  this.getAttribute('data-item'); // get index of the array cell

      this.closest('.single-project__model-wrapper').style.display='none';
      remCollectionAlert.classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("remove-mod__title").innerHTML = dataTitle;

      let existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')); // get out an array from local storage
      existingEntries.splice(dataItem, 1); //trying to delete an item

      });
});
```

Но вместо удаления данных с индексом 0 (например) из массива этот код existingEntries.splice (0, 1); удаляет все, оставляя только один элемент в массиве.

```
 let existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray'));
 console.log(existingEntries);
```

Вот что я вижу в консоли

[image: sample first]

Я собираюсь удалить, например, элемент с индексом 0:

```
console.log(existingEntries.splice(0, 1));
```

И вот результат, он вообще мне не понятен.

[image]

Если вместо 0 будет другое значение, то вообще все будет удалено.
Почему это происходит, я не могу понять. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

PS: Здесь [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) я уже был. И вроде делаю как описано, но не работает. Что-то упускаю и не могу понять что.

Comment: splice изменяет сам массив и возвращает удаленные элементы

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить existingEntries.splice(0, 1) и потом вывести мутированный массив console.log(existingEntries)

Comment: @Samoedy Так работает! Но почему. В чем причина? Я очень Вам благодарен я ведь уже второй день с этой элементарщиной разобраться не мог. На  developer.mozilla я ничего подобного в описании не заметил.

Comment: slice и splice - это две большие разницы (у вас ссылка на slice а вопрос про splice).

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk как уже говорили выше, метод splice мутирует исходный массив, то есть удаляет в нем указанные элементы и смещает индексы, а возвращает только удаленные. Когда вы вызываете console.log(existingEntries.splice(0, 1)), то видите только удаленные элементы, в то время как удаление элементов из исходного массива успешно произошло. Когда вы сперва вызываете existingEntries.splice(0, 1), а потом console.log(existingEntries), то видите итоговый массив уже без удаленных элементов